# What kind of front end/ gui is used with trading applications?

Tags: c++, user-interface, frontend

I was wondering what kind of front end is used for trading applications. Coming from a quant background, I was always only concerned with research and back end of the application but am at a total loss when it comes to front end/ gui. Most of my coding has been done in c++ and I am using just a config file to pass parameters.

Now it turns out due to regulatory reasons, this might not suffice. I need to have a front end which can start/ stop the strategy, change parameters and fetch order and trade history. So question boils down to this, How can I create a simple ui which can sit on another machine, communicate with the colocated machine and do all this.

Initially I thought of using web/javascript but not much is out there regarding this. Qt is another option but I suspect it will require substantial rewrite of the code and learning.

What is the preferred front end for medium to high frequency trading applications which have the core strategy running in c++?

Comment: Probably whatever the developer(s) were familiar with. Surely, it makes very little difference what the UI is written in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming from the industry, I can tell you with certainty: Anything goes. I have worked on trading application frontends using MFC, QT, Forms, WPF. Java is quite popular too, as are homegrown abominations.  One non-obvious way to communicate with the colocated machine is Citrix or Remote Desktop.

You do need to make sure that you have well defined behavior in case the client crashes, server crashes, connection between them freezes/gets lost, connection to the market gets lost, connection comes back, etc. Tell the trader how it will react in these situations, in advance. If it doesn't make sense, the trader won't use your application.

Further details depend on many variables. Are you an ISV, or is it an in-house application? Are you working in an arcade? Which markets are you connecting to? Does your hosted co-lo environment have some special rules in regards to what can run there?

Comment: "Forms" ... you mean html/ web forms? I have myself seen excel being used. As I am on a bit of deadline so wanted to know which would be the quickest (even if a little dirty). And what should be the long term option? Since my backend is ready, just want to get it out asap. have started with qt but still understanding basics there.

Comment: The quickest is certainly Citrix (write a non-remote GUI, remote the entire Windows GUI with Citrix). Excel works. If you separate the trading engine and frontend and put them on different machines, you need to make sure that you have a kill switch that works when it's needed, for example when you lose the connection between front end and trading engine.

Comment: @NaveenSharma: Forms means this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms

Comment: @Peter, am not an ISV or in arcade. Working currently as an independent quant consultant. doing everything as of now to retain control of all processes. exchange will be NSE in India and no special rules as far as i know. Finally, would you recommend QT for the long haul?

Comment: @NaveenSharma In the long haul I would recommend something that easily survives a potential port to Linux. Since you are already familiar with C++, I'd recommend Qt for the GUI. But you might prefer using something with less dependencies for the communication between the 2 systems, that's up to you.

Comment: @Peter, that was precisely why I was going for Qt. As I am totally clueless in this area, do you mind elaborating a bit on "something with less dependencies for the communication between the 2 systems" if possible.

Comment: @NaveenSharma This is a bit off topic, but some people (i.e. me) consider it prudent to avoid adding unnecessary library dependencies. If you already use boost (www.boost.org) or another framework in your project that provides platform independent networking, you could avoid using any Qt in the trading engine. Following the same reasoning, if you are not yet using any other framework that provides platform independent networking, use Qt. But all this is highly subjective.

Comment: @Peter, I am using boost, though not for networking yet. SO If I understand correctly, one option would be backend + networking (boost) + entirely independent front end. Or integrated backend, frontend using Qt. thanks, a lot learnt!

Comment: @NaveenSharma Yes. And if you only use asynchronous message passing (no pointers, always send all data) to communicate between trading engine and GUI, you can start with the integrated solution and by replacing the message passing layer with one that works over the network you split into independent GUI / trading engine. Btw, I would avoid using the terms "frontend" and "backend" because in trading these terms mean something entirely different than in software.